# How to Save and Retrieve a Variable to/from Persistence in iOS?

Tags: ios, nsstring

Whenever I call my method ***generateTitleString*** I need to display a text to the user that says "***Video X***", where "***X***" is the number of the last video displayed to the user plus 1. If I use the below code, it is generating always the same number, which is 1.

```
- (NSString *) generateTitleString
{
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video %d", count+1];
    return title;
}
```

*How can I save and retrieve in/from persistence the value of the last video displayed so each time I display the "**Video X**" text it shows the increased count?*

Thxs.

Comment: Going like 1, 2, 3 is not really random: `for i in 1..<10 { print("test\(i)") }`

Comment: if i don't know max number then

Comment: Why don't you thoroughly explain what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Explain your scenario or need in brief that what you exactly want!

Comment: please check the updated question.

Comment: If you want sequential numbers, why are you using `arc4random`? Just increment a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not increasing the variable **count** and that is why you get always ***"Video 1"***.

**UPDATE**: You can create a class where you can keep all your global variables (like "*count*"). In this example, I'm naming this class **GlobalData**. You also need to use **User Defaults** to permanently save the value of some of your variables.

Try the next.

### **GlobalData.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalData : NSObject

+ (NSInteger) getCount;

+ (void) setCount:(NSInteger)newCount;

@end
```

### **GlobalData.m:**

```
#import "GlobalData.h"

#define COUNT_USER_DEFAULT_KEY @"COUNT_USER_DEFAULT_KEY"

@implementation GlobalData

/**
* It returns the number of the last video displayed.
*
* @param 
* @return the number of the last video displayed
*/
+ (NSInteger) getCount
{
    NSInteger count;
    NSString* recoveredValue;

    // init variables
    count = 0;
    recoveredValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:COUNT_USER_DEFAULT_KEY];

    // If the recovered value is not NIL, we convert it to an integer.
    if (recoveredValue != nil)
        count = [recoveredValue integerValue];

    return count;
}

/**
* It sets the number of the last video displayed with the value of input "newCount".
*
* @param newCount    Number of the last video displayed.
* @return 
*/
+ (void) setCount:(NSInteger)newCount
{
    // Save user info in NSUserDefaults.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)newCount] forKey:COUNT_USER_DEFAULT_KEY];

    // Writes NSUserDefaults on disk.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

@end
```

### View Controller:

```
#import "GlobalData.h"

@implementation

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSString *) generateTitleString
{
    NSString *title;
    NSInteger count;

    // Getting count and increasing it.
    count = [GlobalData getCount];
    count = count + 1;        

    // Creating title by using 'count'.
    title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video %d", count];

    // Updating 'count'
    [GlobalData setCount:count];

    return title;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay now it is showing video 2 always.can you please tell me how can i declare count.

Comment: I just updated the answer, check it out. I'm assuming you are declaring the variable count in a UIViewController.

Comment: No I'm also using same.But as you said  when ever we came to that view then it will start from video 1.But I need entire app when ever we call this method i need to increment from last one.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. It's working but when i close my app and reopen then it is showing video 1 again.sorry for the trouble.so is their any way to get the string when we close app and reopen then it will increment from last value

Comment: Thank you very much it's working. one more thing can you please tell me one thing.This will work upto app is installed when i uninstall my app in that case how can we achieve this

Comment: @Bittoo Yes, sure. In order to save a value and persist it, even when the app is uninstalled, you can use: (1) Apple CloudKit (to save it in Apple's server). (2) Your own server with your own database. (3) Apple Keychain.

Comment: Thank you very much it really worth full info.

Comment: Sure @Bittoo . I also updated your question so it explains itself better. Take care :)